# REST API document conversion service resource Url

Tags: rest

Subjective I know but how should I name a service which converts documents to PDF to conform to RESTful principles? The method accepts a document as content and returns the converted document stream.

Currently the resource Url is POST Api/Convert. The content of the request is not stored so I don't think POST is appropriate.

My initial thought is GET Api/Document?type=PDF Would this follow best practice?

Comment: how would you send the pdf content to this (GET) endpoint ?

Comment: @marcinn Good point - perhaps a POST of the raw document and then a GET of the converted version rather than attempting 2 actions in 1 request is best